# Cors blocks my request even after enabling it in config

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, http, spring-security, cors

Hey I am building a web site in react and I tried fetching data from my backend server built in spring but It won't work. I added CorsConfigurationSource to my security config yet it still doesnt work.
My cors security config:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
     CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration=new CorsConfiguration();
     corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
     corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
     corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
     UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
     source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
     return source;
}
```

The error that I end up getting: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/olGCD.png\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olGCD.png%5C)
My fetch request (I am posting user credentials):

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
      method: "POST",
      mode:'cors',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams(tempLoginCredentials),
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS in Google Chrome is a bit special on `localhost`.
Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work).

On top of that, PORT does matter in CORS. Note that you enabled port 3000 in your Spring config, but are fetching 8080.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, I thought I was supposed to put in the url of site that is able to share resources, changed that but still nothing thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more headers and OPTIONS method.

```
config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
```